# Get scope from within model in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm currently building a query like this:

```
account.sales.method_needing_more_account_info(account)
```

I want to be able determine account based on the scope that is already there, simplifying the method calls to something like this:

```
account.sales.method_pulling_account_from_scope
```

I'm doing this as the account model holds certain settings that determine how sales data is presented and alter the queries to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scopes are **class methods** and therefore unaware of instance variables and attributes, in order to do what you are asking you have to stick to your first code sample.

The alternative would be to write a method that returns the data

**Rails 2**

```
# returns an array of results
def more_account_info
  self.sales.all(:conditions => [])
end

# i've also added an initializer to allow for returning a scope before
# details here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes
class ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :conditions, lambda { |*args| {:conditions => args} }
end

# which allows for me to return a scoped object (chainable)
def more_account_info
  scope = Account.scoped({})
  scope = scope.sales
  scope = scope.conditions ""
end
```

or in rails 3 you could return an Arel object (chainable)

**Rails 3**

```
# returns an arel object rather than an array of results
def more_account_info
  self.sales.where("")
def
```

Comment: The rails 3 approach you have seems like the best one.  Thanks!